# How to upgrade the Azure Functions project runtime from v3 to v4?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

Trying to upgrade my local vs code azureFunctions.projectRuntime from v3 to v4 for my azure function app written in python.

I have installed the azure function tools 4 using both the installer and the npm command, installed .net runtime 6.0 sdk but still not able to see the Azure Functions v4.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are a few pre-requistes to be followed for the upgrade. So please be aware of the breaking changes between v3 and v4 as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-python#breaking-changes-between-3x-and-4x).

You need run the `pre-upgrade validator` and also confirm before the upgrade process. The steps are outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-python#run-the-pre-upgrade-validator)

You also need to [upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-python#upgrade-your-local-project) your local project before you publish it to Azure.

While running it on windows you need to ensure that you have enabled .NET 6.0 which is a must for the v 4.x Function app runtime and then republish your app.

> az functionapp config set --net-framework-version v6.0 -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -n <APP_NAME>

More information, for your reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-python#prepare-for-migration).

Comment: Those are valid for upgrading an already deployed v3 version but I am trying to update the local setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed .net 6.0 already as mentioned above and installed Azure Function Tools 4. When I upgraded the VS Code from 1.51 to the latest one, I uninstalled Azure Functions, Account, and Resources extensions. Now it is able to detect the Azure Function runtime v4.